# What is a good replacement format for mp4?

Tags: video, format, open-source

I want to step over to a free and open source video format, but wherever I look I can't find one. Do you guys know one perhaps? It will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to take a look at [Matroska Media Container](https://www.matroska.org).

> Matroska is usually found as `.MKV` files (matroska video), `.MKA` files
>   (matroska audio) and `.MKS` files (subtitles) and `.MK3D` files
>   (stereoscopic/3D video). It is also the basis for `.webm` (WebM) files.

Matroska is similar in concept to other containers like AVI, MP4, or Advanced Systems Format (ASF), but is entirely open in specification, with implementations consisting mostly of open source software.

Matroska  can support all known audio and video compression formats by design. It can support many of the more advanced features that modern audio and video compression formats will offer, such as Variable Bitrate audio encoding ( VBR ), or Variable Framerate video encoding (VFR) overcoming limitations of other frameworks like Video For Windows (VfW) framework used by containers such as `.AVI`.

> To make sure it will also be capable of coping with the future
>   standards it is based on a very flexible underlying framework called
>   EBML, allowing to add more functionalities to the container format
>   without breaking backwards compatibility with older softwares and
>   files.

Useful resouces

- [How can I create Matroska files ?](https://www.matroska.org/technical/guides/faq/index.html)
- [Source Code Repository](https://www.matroska.org/team/source-code.html)
- [License](https://www.matroska.org/node/47)
- [Surgeforce project](https://sourceforge.net/projects/matroska/)

---

Acknowledgements

1. [Matroska](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroska)
2. [Matroska Media Container - Homepage](https://www.matroska.org)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed and helpful answer, I will definitely look into this!